# generating rails routes with specific model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a training website where I'm trying to generate dynamic routes for content based on the content title, which is a column in the database. I got pretty far, but I'm having issues with the last part.

Let's say that the content title is "Business Travel," i.e. a training course on business travel. With the code shown below, the link_to helper method in the template generates the link like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/courses/Business Travel
```

What I need is for the words to be separated by dashes, like how Stack Overflow question URLs are formatted.

Is there a built-in method for this? Or do I have to write a helper function that manipulates the content object's title property into something URL-friendly? Or... am I doing this completely the wrong way?

**contentcontroller.rb**

```
class ContentController < ApplicationController

before_action :signed_in_user

def tracks
    end

def courses
    @courses = Content.all
end

def show
        @course = Content.find_by_title(params[:title])
end

end
```

**content.rb**

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :title, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true

end
```

**courses.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Tracks') %>
<div class="container">
    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
        <div class="row">
            <%= link_to course_path(course.title) do %>
                <div class="col-md-12 course-box content-link centertext">
                    <strong><%= course.title %></strong>
                    <p><%= course.description %></p>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/courses/:title', to: 'content#show', via: 'get', as: 'course'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what you are looking for is slugged url. Have a look at `friendly_id` gem

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

It's super easy to get started. Look under `Rails Quickstart` section and that should get you up to speed.

For your convenience.

In your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'friendly_id'
```

Run the following commands in your terminal

```
rails generate friendly_id
rails generate migration add_slug_to_content slug:string
```

Edit your generated migration file to include

```
add_index :contents, :slug, unique: true
```

Run the rake migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

Add the following to your content class

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

   validates :title, presence: true
   validates :description, presence: true
end
```

That should automatically take care of converting the URL to model id for you :)